# How to force pydev output to pydev console?

Tags: pydev

every running will output result to a new console like this:

[image: Unexpected output console]

I just wondering is it possible to output to pydev console(like below) by default

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the interactive console (i.e.: `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`), a subsequent use of `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` should run the current file in the console. See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for more details.